# Matlab Kalman Filter for 3D Position

Tags: 3d, kalman-filter

I am trying to find 3D position using Kalman filter .Kindly it would be so nice if some one please help me how I can modify my 1D code to 3D .I am confused about the this filter.

```
i = 100; % time points  
s=[i, 1]; % size
r=22; % actual value  
Q=4e-5; %  variance 
R=0.23; % measurement variance  
m = r + sqrt(R)*randn(s); % measured value 
v_est=zeros(s); % estimated variace :taken after measurment 
x_hat_minus=zeros(s); %estimation before measurment at n-1 step 
v_minus_est=zeros(s); % variance estimated before measurments 
K=zeros(s); % Kalman factor 
x_hat(1) = 21.5; % estimation starts at this value       
v_est(1) =1; % error in variance  
 for n = 2:i    
% step:1 time update 
x_hat_minus(n) = x_hat(n-1); %estimating the current value based on previous    estimations       
v_minus_est(n) = v_est(n-1)+Q; %variance prediction
% step 2: Measurement Update 
K(n) = v_minus_est(n)/( v_minus_est(n)+R ); %calculating kalman factor
x_hat(n) = x_hat_minus(n)+K(n)*(m(n)-x_hat_minus(n)); %estimation    
v_est(n) = (1-K(n))*v_minus_est(n); %variance achieved in last estimation 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read your code fully (haven't used matlab for a year or so), but it appears you have implemented only a first-order Kalman filter (?), which I believe nuts out as a simple IIR filter once the gain has settled.

*Anyways* ...

To answer your question: *Simply implement 3 Kalman filters*, one for each axis **X**, **Y** and **Z**

As they are orthogonal they are independent from each other and live in their own little universe.

Assuming single order, you can build a 3x3 state matrix if you want, but it's more transparent to go with 3 1x1's (or better yet 3 x second-order 2x2's, if you haven't already).followed